# How to make a file which is a shortcut to the middle of a video file?

Tags: video, shortcuts, vlc-media-player

Is there any way, with vlc or whatever other program, to make a file that I could double click and it would automatically start a local video file on my computer and start it from there?

Comment: I'm sure there are video players that have command line parameters on where in a video to begin playing, so write a script that runs the video player with that parameter.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://vlc-videolan.10979.n7.nabble.com/Start-time-parameter-for-vlc-td1875.html or this: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r27646640-Starting-a-video-MP4-file-from-VLC-at-a-specific-start-time-